# Sql Server Merge Statement in Python

Tags: python, sql-server

I am using sqlalchemy / pyodbc with MS SQL Server, and am trying to execute a raw SQL merge statement. If I take my query string and paste it into SQL Server Management Studio it works fine, but I can't seem to get it to work from Python. I've looked around a bit and can't seem to find questions on a similar issue. I realize this is quite possibly driven by issues specific to my setup but am hoping someone is able to help or at least point me in the right direction. Minimal example is below:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
engine = sa.create_engine('[your engine]')
metadata = sa.MetaData(engine)

t1 = sa.Table('test1', metadata, 
              sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False),
              sa.Column('name', sa.String(50)), schema='dbo')
t2 = sa.Table('test2', metadata, 
              sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False),
              sa.Column('name', sa.String(50)), schema='dbo')
t1.create()
t2.create()

query = "INSERT INTO dbo.test1 (id, name) VALUES (5, 'someguy')"
engine.execute(query)
mq = """MERGE dbo.test2 AS Target USING dbo.test1 AS Source ON
        Target.id = Source.id
        WHEN MATCHED THEN 
             UPDATE SET Target.name = Source.name
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
             INSERT (id, name) VALUES (Source.id, Source.name);"""
engine.execute(mq)
```

Comment: On its face, it looks fine to me. Is there an error you're getting?

Comment: No error, nothing that looks unusual - just 0 rows in dbo.test2.

Comment: How are you verifying zero rows? In SSMS? Is it possible that you're in some sort of (uncommitted) transaction in your app?

Comment: It's set to autocommit. I can run other queries fine and see results immediately. For example, if I manually try to run insert INTO t2 from t1 it works. I've also tried running insert into, then changing t1, and then re-running to the merge to see if the update is firing just not the insert. But neither seem to work.

Comment: I am just splitting the query into and update and insert into statement. It seems to work fine. Not sure if I just stumbled into some strange bug or just something weird going on on my end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into similar problem as well (statement can be executed in SSMS but does nothing when ran in Python). Here is how I got it to work:

```
conn = engine.connect()
conn = conn.execution_options(autocommit=True)
conn.execute(stmt)
conn.close()
```

with stmt as the merge statement.

Comment: I don't know why the other one does not work but this one worked for me as well at the first attempt! Thank you so much for sharing this, you made my day!!