# Python execute SQL merge statement nothing happens but same statement works in SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I have a dataframe that I upload to a temp table. This loads correctly (I have put a break point in to check).

I then run a merge statement but nothing appears to happen, the rows are not appended to the target table (and the rows do not already exist in the target table).

When I copy the merge statement into SQL Server and execute the statement then it works I can see the new rows. So I am a little lost as to why the statement doesn't work when I run it in Python?

All my code is below.

```
def my_function(database: str, df: pd.DataFrame) -> None:

    
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server};"
                                     "SERVER=MY_PC\SQLEXPRESS;"
                                     "DATABASE=" + database + ";"
                                     "Trusted_Connection=yes")

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params))
cnxn = engine.connect()

q = """ 
CREATE TABLE #tdata(hq_id int, 
time_stamp datetime,
pressure float,
p_atom float,
npt2 float,
qstate float)
"""
cnxn.execute(q)    

# upload data into temp table
df.to_sql('tempdb..#tdata', cnxn, if_exists='replace', index=False)

# now do the merge
mq = """
MERGE p_region p
USING [tempdb..#tdata] d
ON p.hq_id = d.hq_id 
    and p.time_stamp = d.time_stamp
WHEN NOT MATCHED by TARGET
    THEN INSERT (hq_id, time_stamp, pressure, p_atom, npt2, qstate)
    VALUES(d.hq_id, d.time_stamp, d.pressure, d.p_atom, d.npt2, d.qstate);
"""
cnxn.execution_options(autocommit=True)
cnxn.execute(mq)
cnxn.close()
engine.dispose()
```

Comment: Think you might need to explicitly commit your changes, using `cnxn.commit()` after your execute line.

Comment: Do you have a table called `[tempdb..#tdata]` in your database? Perhaps you mean to use `[tempdb]..[#tdata]` instead, or even more simply `#tdata`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I have tried #tdata which is what I normally use however still nothing happens

Comment: duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36438371/sql-server-merge-statement-in-python